# Why is one who's influenced by a Persian priest liable to death?

Tags: avodah-zarah, maseches-shabbos

It says in [Shabbat 75b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.75b?lang=bi) that if a magosh tries to influence a Jew to adopt even a single one of his customs, that Jew should be put to death:

> אמר רב זוטרא בר טוביה אמר רב: ... והלומד דבר אחד מן המגוש חייב מיתה
>
> Rav Zutra bar Toviya said that Rav said: ... one who learns even one matter from a Magosh, a Persian priest, is liable to receive the death penalty.

So my question is: why such a harsh punishment against a fellow Jew just for adopting a custom from a magosh?

Comment: @AlBerko it is in halacha https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.179.19

Comment: @AlBerko https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.179.23

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94558/discussion-between-al-berko-and-hazoriz).

Comment: @AlBerko i meant https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.21b.8

Comment: A Zoroastrian priest is probably a better translation for מגוש https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi